# Generating virtual data in R under specified conditions

Tags: r

I am quite new to programming, and I'm just starting using R, but haven't been able to have this question answered from more experienced users. So hopefully this will be useful for other people as well.

My dataset is made of items (rows) categorised with integers from 0 to 4,
which represent degrees of my discrete variable. To which I have two years data, 1980 and then from 1996 (columns). During that time, the items can remain in the same category through that period, or be graded to other degrees in both directions. Like for example:

`1980  1996
a)  1    1
b)  2    4
c)  4    1`

What I want to do is generate virtual data for intermediate years:

Meaning that when I split my real period from 1980 -1996 into a multitude of virtual datasets with 1980-1984-1988-1992-1996 for my example I could get:

`1980 1984 1988 1992 1996
a)  1     1    1   1    1
b)  2     2    3   4    4
c)  4     4    3   2    1`

or:

`1980 1984 1988 1992 1996
a)  1     1    1   1    1
b)  2     3    3   3    4
c)  4     3    2   2    1`

I could use a random number generator, but my items cannot jump categories or change grading direction. So if for example, item d) is upgraded from 1 to 4, my virtual datasets can only be one of four options:

`1980 1984 1988 1992 1996
d)  1     1    2   3    4
d)  1     2    2   3    4
d)  1     2    3   3    4
d)  1     2    3   4    4`

it cannot be

`1980 1984 1988 1992 1996
d)  1     2    1   4    4`

nor

`1980 1984 1988 1992 1996
d)  1     1    1   3    4`

How can I generate virtual data frames, that follow specific conditions that allow it to remain grounded in reality?

Any help or advise will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this

```
df <- read.table(text = "
1980  1996
1    1
2    4
4    1", header = T)


df.new <- data.frame(X1980 = NULL, X1984 = NULL, X1988 = NULL, X1992 = NULL, X1996 = NULL)

for(i in 1:nrow(df)){

  lst <- ifelse(df$X1980[i] > df$X1996[i], 
                list(sort(sample(df$X1980[i]:df$X1996[i],3,replace = T), decreasing = T)),
                list(sort(sample(df$X1980[i]:df$X1996[i],3,replace = T), decreasing = F)))

  lst <- c(df$X1980[i], unlist(lst), df$X1996[i])

  df.new <- rbind(df.new, data.frame(X1980 = lst[1], 
                                     X1984 = lst[2], 
                                     X1988 = lst[3], 
                                     X1992 = lst[4], 
                                     X1996 = lst[5]))
}

df.new

  X1980 X1984 X1988 X1992 X1996
1     1     1     1     1     1
2     2     3     4     4     4
3     4     4     3     2     1
```

Comment: This works great, it follows all the my conditions so the data generated is reality based. 
However, once it always generates the same result, would it be possible to randomise the outcome, so I could get different possible datasets that follow my conditions?

Comment: it should generate random results since I have used `sample`

Comment: Sorry it was my bad, the df.new are indeed different, I must have been doing something wrong. 
Ideally I would like to get quite a few simulations to plot, could you help me place your loop within another loop that generates x different iterations of df.new? 

And because I'm only looking at head (df.new), how could I add a warning-message function, that lets me know if any item breaks the conditions (jumps a category or changes grading direction). Or is this pointless, as the code would never allow for it to happen? 

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
> set.seed(2017)
> 
> df <- data.frame(x1984 = c(1,2,4), x1996 = c(1,4,1))
> df
  x1984 x1996
1     1     1
2     2     4
3     4     1
>  
> df$x1988 <- df$x1984 + c(sample(0:1,1),sample(0:1,1), sample(0:1,1) )
> df$x1992 <- df$x1988 + c(sample(0:1,1),sample(0:1,1), sample(0:1,1) )
> 
> df <- df[,order(names(df))]
> 
> df
  x1984 x1988 x1992 x1996
1     1     2     2     1
2     2     3     4     4
3     4     4     5     1
```

Comment: Your solution looks promising but I get an error message I can't solve, saying :
Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) : 
  invalid 'size' argument

Comment: the code as is doesn't cause the error, but I could reproduce the error using the following command `sample(0:1, NULL)` ,  I would check the second argument you are giving the function `sample` make sure it's not a `NULL`

Comment: I don't know what I'm doing wrong, because I'm using `c(sample(0:1,1)`, but when replacing it with `sample(0:1, NULL)` I do indeed get the same exact error:
 Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) : 
  invalid 'size' argument

Answer (score 0):

given the matrix myMat,

```
myMat <- matrix(c(1, 2, 4, 1, 4, 1), 3)
```

You can use `apply` and `approx` with `ceiling` as follows:

```
t(apply(myMat, 1, function(x) ceiling(approx(x=x, n=5)$y)))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    1    1    1    1
[2,]    2    3    3    4    4
[3,]    4    4    3    2    1
```

`ceiling` is used to convert to integers. You could replace this with `floor` or `round` if desired. To convert to a data.frame, you would wrap the output in `data.frame` and could add names using `setNames`.

```
setNames(data.frame(t(apply(myMat, 1, function(x) ceiling(approx(x=x, n=5)$y)))),
         seq(1980, 1996, 4))
```

This returns

```
  1980 1984 1988 1992 1996
1    1    1    1    1    1
2    2    3    3    4    4
3    4    4    3    2    1
```

Comment: It is really short and easy to use, but my items can't jump categories and always keep their grading direction throughout the full period, and this method generated items which break these conditions, like:  2 2 1 3 4.

Comment: Your comment is unclear. There is no 2 2 1 3 4 in the above example. You should probably clarify or provide a more appropriate example.

Comment: Sorry. I meant to say that when I run the code on my full dataset, for some of those items it generated virtual data like in the example I mentioned. `1980 1984 1988 1992 1996
y)   2      2        1       3       4` Which breaks my conditions